# Error while embedding Twitter Timeline on Shiny

Tags: r, twitter, shiny

I was trying the solution to this question:

[How can I embed a twitter timeline in a Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619162/how-can-i-embed-a-twitter-timeline-in-a-shiny-app?rq=1)

This is my code :

```
library(shiny)
runApp(list(ui = fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script('!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)    [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?\'http\':\'https\';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");')),
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel()
    , mainPanel(
      a("BreakingNews",class="twitter-timeline",href = "https://twitter.com/BreakingNews", "data-widget-id"="553910163694821376")     
               )
               )
 )
, server = function(input, output, session){

}
)
)
```

I am getting this error :

```
Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use
```

Comment: Please update shiny, you might be running an older version as you example works fine for me. I think this is a directory error

Comment: @pops would you know why I am getting only the handle name and not the timeline along with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tweaked the code a bit and at least the error disappeared.

```
library(shiny)
      shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script('!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)    [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?\'http\':\'https\';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");')),
  titlePanel(""),
  sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(),
      mainPanel(
      a("@ChannelNewsAsia",class="twitter-timeline",href="https://twitter.com/ChannelNewsAsia", "data-widget-id"=553910391399383040)     
               )
               )
 )
)
```

But now the screen only shows the handle name i.e @ChannelNewsAsia which on clicking takes the user to the specified link.
There is still no timeline widget appearing on the ui

Comment: ok. so i published the same on the browser and works fine. Just the way I expect it to. Guess the shiny window is not the best place to test code locally.